# MySql Syntax EROR Gallery PIC > safe_query('SELECT picID FROM cb_v1_gallery_pictures LIMIT -1 , 0')

Tags: php

HERE IS THE PHP CODE  WHIT THE ERROR:

```
public function randomPic($galleryID = 0){

if ($galleryID) {
        $only = "WHERE `galleryID` = " . (int)$galleryID;
    } else {
        $only = '';
    }
    $anz = mysqli_num_rows(safe_query("SELECT picID FROM `" . PREFIX . "gallery_pictures` $only"));
    $selected = rand(1, $anz);
    $start = $selected -1;
    $pic = mysqli_fetch_array(
        safe_query(
            "SELECT `picID` FROM `" . PREFIX . "gallery_pictures` $only LIMIT $start , $anz"
        )
    );

    return $pic['picID'];
}
```

> Query failed
>
> MySQL error no.: 1064
>        MySQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '-1 , 0' at line 1   SQL: SELECT `picID` FROM
>   `cb_v1_gallery_pictures` LIMIT -1 , 0

```
safe_query(
  "SELECT `picID` FROM `" . PREFIX . "gallery_pictures` $only LIMIT $start , $anz"
)
```

I'm become this error : safe_query('SELECT `picID` FROM `cb_v1_gallery_pictures`  LIMIT -1 , 0')

Anybody can Help? THX

Comment: Your limits are `-1` and `0`. That won't work.

Comment: limit start from 0. so `LIMIT -1,0` will never work